# Particle system on event

Tags: aframe

I'd like to have the particle system appear at the end of my project, like confetti. What I have is this, but it is not working, nor is setting the visibility to false, then true.  Not sure which attribute I can use to set the visibility off, then on.

html:

```
<a-entity id="confetti" particle-system="accelerationSpread: 20 0 20; color: white; enabled: false;  particleCount: 300; opacity: 0.3; preset: default; size: 0.5; velocityValue: 0 15 0" position="5.584 1.250 -1.4"  ></a-entity>
```

js:

```
if (score == 7) {
    function tada() {
        congrats.setAttribute('visible', true);
        confetti.setAttribute('enabled', true);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Even if it's deprecated: `resetProperty('enabled')` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`confetti.object3D.visible = false` or `confetti.removeAttribute('particle-system')`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sets visible to false or removes the attribute...this answer is atomic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(confetti, 'particle-system.enabled', true);
```

Apparently `setAttribute` doesn't support multiple levels of components.

It's documented here:
https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/utils.html#setcomponentproperty-entity-componentname-value-delimiter